# Are short movies on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should shorts be in-topic? That includes for instance:

- the three [blender-movies](http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/blender-open-projects/)
- [La Jeteé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_jet%C3%A9e)
- most of the work of [Charlie Chaplin](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000122/) before 1923

If we want to exclude short-movies, where is the line? 30 Minutes?

Answer (score 6):

Since they are not only movies by name, but usually also encompass all aspects of "long" movies, they should be perfectly Ok, I think.

Comment: What does *Since they are not only by name movies* mean?

Comment: @Tshepang This was just a small remark to short movies being movies by name, because, well, the words "short movie" contain the word "movie". Not that this alone justifies them for being on-topic, therefore the "but"-part.