# Should TV-movies off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Final TV Decision](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/final-tv-decision)

In an comment to [another question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/66) @Aarthi states:

> According to Princeton University, a television show is "a program broadcast by television," which Wikipedia extends to "a segment of content which is intended to be broadcast on television" either once or recurring. By definition TV movies, miniseries, and television shorts (eg Oh Yeah! Cartoons!) are on-topic for a TV site.

That says indirectly, that TV-movies should be discouraged. Are movies produced for TV or Video-release off-topic?